# Starting an IntentService form a WakefulService

Tags: android, android-service, android-wake-lock, android-intentservice, android-broadcastreceiver

I have a a Broadcast receiver form which I am starting an intent service (say s1) using `startWakefulSerivce(context,i)`.

From the service s1 I am starting another IntentService (say s2) using `startService(i)`. In s1 I am releasing the wakelock with

```
 GCMBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
```

Now will the second IntentService s2 stll hold the wakelock, ie, will it run in background if the device sleeps.
If not how can I start the second Intent Service s2 wakefully like the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now will the second IntentService s2 stll hold the wakelock

No.

> If not how can I start the second Intent Service s2 wakefully like the first one?

IMHO, the best answer is to not have a second `IntentService`, as it is unclear why you are splitting the work across two `IntentService` implementations.

Assuming that you have a reason for the split, your primary options are:

1. Use [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful), which is not tied to having to be started by a `BroadcastReceiver` (though that is certainly a common usage pattern).
2. Manage your own `WakeLock` very carefully.
3. Instead of starting the service directly, use another `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, which starts the service (so you call `sendBroadcast()`). In other words, treat your second `IntentService` the same as your first one. This has security and efficiency ramifications, though.

Comment: Can you please give and example for the 3rd option as to how to send a broadcast message from the first service to another broadcast receiver? Also where do I define the new broadcast receiver. It would be really helpful if you can give a code example

Comment: @Isj: "how to send a broadcast message" -- call `sendBroadcast()`. "Also where do I define the new broadcast receiver" -- presumably alongside where you defined your existing receiver.